# Implementing Search bar functionality - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, uisearchbar

**The Situation**

I have an app which retrieves data from an API I built. After retrieving the data it fill the data into UITableView.

Inside my HTTP request I have the following code which saves the retrieved data into an Array:

```
var dta = []

if let parseJSON = self.son {

                         self.dta = parseJSON
                    }
```

After that I created a search function like so:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
  //  if let id = dta["caseStudyTitle"] as? String
    filtered = dta.filter({ (text) -> Bool in

        //if let id = Summary["caseStudyTitle"] as? String
        let tmp = text as! NSString
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        print("THIS IS TEXT \(text)")
        return range.location != NSNotFound

    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**The Error**

After running the above code I get the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x10ef45c) to 'NSString' (0x460444).
```

At this line:

```
let tmp = text as! NSString
```

**The Data Structure**

Below is the structure of JSON data, the dta variable contains this data.

```
[  
  {  
  "_id":"qweqwqw",
  "caseStudyTitle":"Title",
  "caseStudyLink":"link",
  "sector":"sec one",
  "__v":0
},
{  
  "_id":"qweqwqw",
  "caseStudyTitle":"Title",
  "caseStudyLink":"link",
  "sector":"sec one",
  "__v":0
}, 
{another object},
{another object} ]
```

**The End Game**

I would like to be able to filter the data being displayed on the UITableView.
If a user types something in the search bar the UITableView reloads with the filtered data.

**Also I only need to search the case study title & sector fields.**

If you need more into in order to solve this problem please let me know.

Comment: Are you wanting to filer based on the Title or any of the attributes of the JSON Object?

Comment: @Caleb filter based on title and sector. Only those two fields.

Comment: I would recommend creating a class for the data in the JSON object. It would be much easier to filter and us later on. If you don't want to do that, you can access the title  and sector with `let tempTitle = text["caseStudyTitle"] as! String`.

Comment: @Caleb thank you for the reply. I am just confused as to where and how use that line of code. If you look at my code I have the same line commented out. Any suggestion on how to and where to actually implement this line in the current code? Again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently casting an `NSDictionary` into an `NSString`.

Here is how you can filter based on the title and sector:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      //  if let id = dta["caseStudyTitle"] as? String
        filtered = dta.filter({ (text) -> Bool in

        //Access the title and sectors
        let tmpTitle = text["caseStudyTitle"] as! String
        let tmpSector = text["sector"] as! String

        //Create a range for both
        let range1 = tmpTitle.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        let range2 = tempSector.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        print("THIS IS TEXT \(text)")
        //Return true if either match
        return range1 != nil || range2 != nil

    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you again caleb. i have learned something from this. After implementing your code I am getting the following error. 'value of type Range<index>? has not member location.' Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: An update: Changing the "as! String" to "as! NSString" solves the issue. Though I am not sure why.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn I forgot that `rangeOfString` acted differently for `Strings`. My edit above also fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your dta array contains two dictionary elements, not string elements.  That's why you get an error saying that you can't cast dictionary into nsstring.

let tmp = text as! NSString

Here, text is dictionary, not String.